# Trying to implement uploading products via excel sheet python react

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a simple dashboard built in react and backend with django. I want to implement the feature where user can import an excel sheet from the frontend and be able to add products to the database. I am not sure how I'd be able to do that. Can anyone point me to the right direction?